# How to use context in a function?

Tags: android

I'm very beginner in android , i write this class for check the network connection:

```
public class ConnectivityDetector {
    public static boolean IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and with this code i want call that class:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 if (ConnectivityDetector.IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(AlarmReciever.this)) {
       //write my code
}

    }
}
```

but in this line:

```
if (ConnectivityDetector.IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(AlarmReciever.this))
```

i get this error:
[image]

how can i solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AlarmReciever` is not context, so you can't use `this`. You have the   parameter `Context context` in on receive. You could use that one.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (ConnectivityDetector.IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(context)) {
            //write my code
```